# Best Column type to store files inside custom list

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, development, modern-experience, administration

We have a SharePoint online custom list named Design. Now each item inside the list can have one or multiple files. So what is the best column type to store files?

I can see we have a column for storing Images, but not files.

[image]

Can anyone advice on this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Image columns in SharePoint online lists](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2020/12/06/all-you-need-to-know-about-new-image-column-type-in-sharepoint-online/) to store image against each list item.

However, the image column type allows only one image to attach from your computer (not SharePoint libraries). So, you cannot add multiple images in one image column.

**Source**: [SharePoint Online: All you need to know about New Image column type](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2020/12/06/all-you-need-to-know-about-new-image-column-type-in-sharepoint-online/)

---

For your requirements to add one or multiple files against each list item, you have to use the "Attachments" column for list items.

Generally, attachments column is enabled automatically when you create a new SharePoint list. If it is not enabled for your SharePoint list, you can enable it from List settings > Advanced settings:

[image]

Comment: thanks for your reply... so you mean if i need to store one file, i am use the image column type? to store PDF , word document, etc?

Comment: If you want to store only one image file (png, jpg, jpeg, etc.) against list item, use image column. For storing other type of documents (word, pdf, excel, etc.), you will have to use the attachments column.

Answer (score 0):

As Ganesh Sanap said, if you need to store multiple files in one record, then please use the attachment column.
If each record requires an image, then you can use the image column.

Comment: i do not want to store images i need to store files like pdf, word documents, etc